# Cannot get bootstrap datepicker to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to get the [Datepicker for Bootstrap](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) to work but have been unsuccessful. The datapicker box never shows:

```
<head>
    <title>Pick-a-Date</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Select date</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="input-append date" id="datepick" data-date="<?=date('m-d-Y', strtotime('-25 hours')) ?>" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="<?=date('m-d-Y', strtotime('-25 hours')) ?>">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#datepick').datepicker({
            format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eComEvo/7svU3/2/

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: bootstrap-datepicker.js isn't being loaded in your fiddle - 404

Comment: @dmullings is correct, you are linking to a non-existent file. Btw, when developing JS apps, take the habit of work with the JS console open.

Comment: The site is blocking direct linking. I added the full code from `http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js` to the JS frame. Still does not work. I have it downloaded locally on my test server, so it wouldn't be a reason for it failing.

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eComEvo/7svU3/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the reference to bootstrap datepicker to something that resolves, e.g. //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js, it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/eComEvo/7svU3/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Select date</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="input-append date" id="datepick" data-date="22-05-2014" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="22-05-2014">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$(function() {
    $('#datepick').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });
});
```

Comment: It would appear I have a dysfunctional copy of that referenced from the code in their site. Using the one from the CDN fixes the problem. Thanks!